# Convert bytes::Bytes and std::io::Error into AsyncRead in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have two variables of type `bytes::Bytes` and `std::io::Error`. I need to get the `AsyncRead` version of them, so that I could pass them to the read end of the `tokio::io::copy`. I'm quite new to Rust and got stuck at this. Would highly appreciate your help on this. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```rs
// handle_connection is basically a proxy function that proxies the request to the 
// origin server (redis_server_addr). 
pub async fn handle_connection(self, mut inbound_stream: TcpStream) {
        let mut outbound_stream = TcpStream::connect(self.redis_server_addr.as_str())
            .await
            .unwrap();

        let (client_read_stream, mut client_write_stream) = inbound_stream.split();
        let (mut server_read_stream, mut server_write_stream) = outbound_stream.split();


       // Based on some conditions which is hidden in this code, `fault_err_msg` will be either be set Some(val) or None.
       // 1. If `fault_err_msg` is Some(val), the value should be written directly to 
       // the client (`server_to_client`). 
       // 
       // 2. If `fault_err_msg` is None, then the `req_bytes` should be sent as a request 
       // to the server (`client_to_server`) and the response from the server  
       // should be sent to the client (`server_to_client`).
       let mut fault_err_msg: Option<std::io::Error> = None;
       let mut req_bytes: Bytes = Bytes::from("");

        
        // if `fault_err_msg` is `None`, then we need to pass the req_bytes to the 
        // io::copy in the following async block
        let client_to_server = async {
            io::copy(____, &mut server_write_stream).await?;
            debug!("request proxied to redis server");
            server_write_stream.shutdown().await
        };

        // if `fault_err_msg` is `Some(val)`, then we need to pass the `val` 
        // which is of type `std::io::Error` to the read end of the io::copy in the following async block
        let server_to_client = async {
            io::copy(____, &mut client_write_stream).await?;
            debug!("response sent back to the client");
            client_write_stream.shutdown().await
        };

        let _ = tokio::try_join!(client_to_server, server_to_client).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: `Bytes` can deref into `&[u8]` which already has `AsyncRead` [implemented](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html#impl-AsyncRead-for-%26%5Bu8%5D), but I'm puzzled on the `std::io::Error` prospect, it does not really represent a sequence of bytes so I'm confused what you want it to write...

Comment: Thanks, @kmdreko! For `std::io::Error`, I converted `std::io::Error` -> `String` -> `&[u8]`.

Comment: If you use the bstr crate you can convert `&[u8]` to a `Bstr` which implements `Display` without copying the underlying bytes to an owned `String`.